# How to install a program from a .tar.gz

Tags: installation, command-line, files, compiling, source

I already extracted the file and when I drag the file to the terminal this is the directory I get "   '/home/ali/Downloads/Stencyl-2.1.0  ". Now can someone give me exact instructions for this directory for exactly installing the program.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most respectable software comes with some sort of Readme file. Did you check for a Readme? If there isn't one, provide the source from where you obtained this particular file.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file . Unfortunately I have to flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Why not use the one provided as a DEB or PPA?

Answer (score 2):

Please refrain from using downloads when the software you want can be installed with Ubuntu Software Center using a normal debian installer.

This will install `Stencyl 2.1.0` (and yes you can install the 12.04 version in 12.10)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/games
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install stencyl
```

[image]

This might be required as a post install edit though: http://community.stencyl.com/index.php/topic,10164.msg65559.html#msg65559

Comment: what if did download a source file, how do i compile/install from it

Comment: @user116719 you open the read me that comes along with the source files and use this as a reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: @user116719 according to the official website you will not have to compile this program. You just have to download it, extract it, enter the extracted folder and then run the Stencyl shell script as a user with write privileges. Note that you need to have Java installed. http://www.stencyl.com/stencyl/get/

Comment: would you mind giving me exact instructions as it didn't find sudo apt-get install stencyl and the file also doesn't have a read me, the only thing in the read me is a link to Java's website. and to add to that I couldn't find stencyl in the software centre

Comment: @user116719 Here you can see stencyl is part of this https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/games The 3 commands I have install stencyl (there is nothing else to do).

Answer (score -1):

first check the install or readme file, may be the procedure slightly differs...

but generally :

once in your folder with the terminal

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make install
```

Comment: If you absolutely need to build from source, replacing make install with checkinstall where possible is a great idea, lets you remove packages using ubuntu's install system